# Can anyone explain this code? C# Unity

Tags: unity, c#, 2d, 3d

Can someone explain this code to me?

```
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;

public class WinScreen : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TextMeshProUGUI MovesMadeCounter;
    public TextMeshProUGUI timePlayed;
    public GameObject winScreen;

    private void Update()
    {
        if (winScreen.activeInHierarchy == true)
        {
            Timer.instance.Finish();

            if (Time.time > 30f)
            {
                UserInput.instance.score += (int)(700000 / Time.time % 60);
            }

            Time.timeScale = 0f;
        }

        MovesMadeCounter.text = "Moves Made: " + MovesMade.instance.movesMade;
        timePlayed.text = "Time Played: " + Timer.instance.TimerText.text;
    }
}
```

Here is the script for the `Timer` script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;

public class Timer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static Timer instance;

    public TextMeshProUGUI TimerText;
    private float startTime;
    public bool finished = false;

    private void Start()
    {
        instance = this;

        startTime = Time.time;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (finished == false)
        {
            float time = Time.time - startTime;

            string minutes = ((int)time / 60).ToString();
            string seconds = (time % 60).ToString("f0");

            TimerText.text = minutes + ":" + seconds;
        }
        else
        {
            Time.timeScale = 0f;
        }
    }

    public void Finish()
    {
        finished = true;
    }
}
```

This is for my solitaire game. I kinda know what the code means and does but I just want to double check.

Comment: It is difficult to tell what information you need exactly. How basic do we have to go? Do we need to explain the basic principles of C# syntax? (your question would be off-topic here in that case. We are not here to give you an introductory course to programming.) Or is there just something in particular you don't understand? Can you be more specific about which parts of the above code you understand and which seem mysterious to you? Do you have an idea what it is *supposed* to do? Can you tell us what it actually does?

Comment: As well you would need to post the code what `Timer.instance.Finish()` does.

Comment: is that better? @Philipp

Comment: @DavidA_ No, it's not. We still don't know what you want to know. You say you "kinda know what the code means". Why don't you tell us what you assume so we can confirm or correct your assumptions? That way you spare us the guessing game of what you might misunderstand and what might be obvious to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;
    
public class WinScreen : MonoBehaviour
{
    //reference to a TextMeshPro UI Text Field
    public TextMeshProUGUI MovesMadeCounter;
    //reference to a TextMeshPro UI Text Field
    public TextMeshProUGUI timePlayed;
    //reference to a GameObject on a canvas presumably showing the win screen UI.
    public GameObject winScreen;

    private void Update()
    {
        //if the winScreen is active in the scene
        if (winScreen.activeInHierarchy == true)
        {
            //Access the instance for the Timer singleton and stop the timing, again presumably.
            Timer.instance.Finish();

            //If the time since the application has started exceeds 30 seconds 
            if (Time.time > 30f)
            {
                //increment the users score in the UserInput singleton by thre result of (700000 / Time since application start modulous 60)
                UserInput.instance.score += (int)(700000 / Time.time % 60);
            }

            //reduce the time scale of the game to zero, effectively hard "pausing" it
            Time.timeScale = 0f;
        }

        //update the text fields for the two referenced TextMeshPro UI Text Fields
        MovesMadeCounter.text = "Moves Made: " + MovesMade.instance.movesMade;
        timePlayed.text = "Time Played: " + Timer.instance.TimerText.text;
    }
}
```

Here is how I would interpet it, as Philipp said in his comment this kind of "how long do you want the piece of string" situation. And this is all assuming the method names mean what *i* think they mean, since I cannot see the implementation of them.